# Is there any methods to get 3D image from webcam in c#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision

**I want to calculate depth of an image. So that i can eliminate far objects from the image.**

> Is there any methods to do so in c# with single camera??

Comment: nope :) Extract depth from single camera not possible.

Comment: @ Kiwaa : Thanks for suggestion. Even though i have heard that intensity factor in HSV color space of an image holds that property.

Comment: You heard wrong. Intensity is just a measure of "lightness" or "brightness". It provides no information about distance, except maybe in controlled environments with lighting conditions set up specifically to do so.

Comment: @TNC It's just a different color scheme, it can't store depth information. BTW you mixed up HSV and HSI. HSV doesn't contains intencity

Comment: @ Kris vandermotten && @ kiwaa : Thanks alot.

Comment: It is possible to do with a laser. Google used such a technique for scanning books, making it possible to undistort a picture of a page without having to flatten it or touch it in any way. Here's another example: http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2010-03/video-blazing-fast-book-scanner-captures-flipping-pages-high-speed-camera

Comment: @ Mark Ransom :I am not using laser for a simple winform. Thanks.

Comment: One other possibility is to detect sharpness in the image and eliminate the out-of-focus background. A webcam probably has too much depth-of-field to make this practical though.

Comment: @  Mark Ransom : Is this possible for objects in an image like body and foreground hand??

Comment: As I said it depends on the depth of field of the camera. The difference in position between a body and a hand is almost certainly within the depth of field of a webcam, so it wouldn't be possible. That's why I didn't make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](https://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/winfrom-and-csharp-sample-code-and-download) shows how to get a webcam image using C#. However, just like a photo, it is flat so there is no way to distinguish objects at different distances from the camera. In general, with just one camera and a single photo/image, what you want is impossible.

With one or two cameras that snap two images/photos with some distance in between, you can distinguish depth (just like you do using your two eyes). However, this requires very complex mathematics to first identify the objects and second determine their approximate distance from the camera.

[Kinect uses an infrared camera](http://blogs.howstuffworks.com/2010/11/05/how-microsoft-kinect-works-an-amazing-use-of-infrared-light/) that creates a low-resolution image to measure the distance to objects in front of the camera, so that it can distinguish the player from the background. I read somewhere that Kinect cameras can be attached to a normal computer, but I don't know about the software or mathematics you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

If you illuminate a straight line with a laser at an angle to the scene, the displacement of the line will correspond exactly to the height of the object. This only gives the height along a single line, subject to the resolution of your camera. If you need a complete 3D scan you'll need to move the laser and take multiple pictures.

Answer (score 0):

a c# reference would be needed for each frame as the streaming  video file comes in.  at the start of the streaming the subject will need to turn their head and spin so a series of measurements can be captured from the subject. this then could be feed to a second camera like unity 3d a virtual camera that transposes a 3d image over the top of the streamed image. there are a lot of mobile phone apps that can capture 3d objects with a series of still frames i had one on my galaxy s6 also the galaxy s6 and up has a depth chip in their cameras that they sold to i phone this is used on the apple 3d camera.  i have been thinking about how to do this also would love to email you about it. to note it would be a similar concept to facial recognition software.